# Getting error when assembling assembly code

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm running Linux mint 16 KDE and this is my first time trying assembly language I installed nasm as my assembler I can assemble my code with it but it throws me this error when I try to make it executable. I have no idea what any of this means because as I said before I'm new to assembly any help with getting this to run would be nice I'm attaching a screenshot the error I am getting when trying to run the script and this is the code in the script I am trying to run.

```
section .data
        msg:    db "Hello World!"
        msg_L: equ $-msg

section .text
        global_start:
_start:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov ecx, msg
        mov edx, msg_L
        int 80h

        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 80h
```

[image: The error I am getting when trying to run the file.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space after the `global` keyword:

```
section .text
        global _start
_start:
        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
```

Also note that the `:` are not required for declaring your entry point.

Comment: Alright that eliminated the
ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol_start; defaulting to 00000000004000b0 error I was getting but its still saying its incompatible with i386:x86-64 output.

Comment: @Gumpy Try using `nasm -f elf64 yourASMfile.asm` to the linker.

Comment: It may "work", but you've still got 32-bit code there. Try `ld -melf_i386 ... ` to tell `ld` we want a 32-bit executable. Or use 64-bit system call numbers (sys_write equ 1) and the `syscall` instruction for real 64-bit code.